# Two Parallel Lines Give Rise to a Third Parallel Naturally

Tags: euclidean-geometry, projective-geometry, plane-geometry

Consider the [image: figure] shown. Here $A, B, C$ and $A', B', C'$ are points in the plane such that $AB$ is parallel to $A'B'$ and $AC$ is parallel to $A'C'$. Further, the points $B, C, B', C'$ are collinear. Let $AC$ intersect $A'B$ at $P$ and let $A'B'$ intersect $AC'$ at $Q$.

> Then $PQ$ is parallel to $BC$.

This problem is certainly amenable to attack via coordinates. But I feel that is an elegant geometric argument hiding in plain sight. In fact, I think somehow projective geometry can be used here, though I am a toddler at projective geometry.

Comment: This is a version (special case) of Desargues' Theorem.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desargues%27s_theorem

Comment: @EthanBolker I fail to see how one can apply Desargues' theorem. Can you please give some details? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe I spoke too quickly. I'll retreat to agreeing with you that projective geometry is key. It's hard to see how just a pair of parallel lines enters. Just a thought: what happens if you try to formulate the question purely projectively, without parallelism: use a different line at infinity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuition about projective geometry is right. This is an instance of [Pappus' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_hexagon_theorem), with one of the nine lines of the configuration being the line at infinity. Keeping one line at infinity, the combinatorics from your configuration can also be drawn like this:

[image: Euclidean Pappus]

Note that $B'$ and $C$ are rather irrelevant: they are the intersection of two lines, but since any two lines intersect (the parallel ones at infinity), there is nothing significant about these points. So the statement goes like this: When $AB\parallel QA'$ and $A'C'\parallel PA$ then $BC'\parallel PQ$.

The corresponding projective situation would look like this:

[image: Projective Pappus]

I started out with a projective version of your input drawing, i.e. with parallels replaced by intersections on a common line. After eliminating the superfluous points, I counted nine points and nine lines. That alone was enough to identify the underlying theorem: there is no other theorem in projective incidence geometry with this few points. Desargues takes ten points and ten lines.

Comment: Can you tell me where I can read projective geometry from? Thanks.

Comment: @caffeinemachine: I like [*Perspectives on Projective Geometry*](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/3642172857) by J. Richter-Gebert. But I should disclose that I've been working under the author for a while, so I might be considered somewhat biased. Chapter 1 provides nine different proofs of Pappus's theorem, with section 1.2 devoted to the Euclidean version with parallels, containing the first two of the nine proofs. I'd argue that the central role of Pappus's theorem in the book makes it a good match if this question here does motivate you to learn more.